# Entity Framework 5. Update many to many relationship gives violation of primary key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I've seen many question like this one, but on those people was calling .Add method on the many to many relationship which I'm not. I'm using WebApi

Am I suppose to call .Clear() and then re-add the updated entities in entity framework 5 or it should be automatically and I'm doing something wrong?

I'm using Unit of Work and the generic Entity Framework Repository pattern.

This is the related code:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Put(PromDto promDto)
{
    var creditCardsIds = string.IsNullOrEmpty(promDto.CreditCards) ? null : promDto.CreditCards.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
    var branchesIds = string.IsNullOrEmpty(promDto.Branches) ? null : promDto.Branches.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);

    var promotion = Uow.Promotions.GetById(promDto.Id);

    promotion.CreditCards = creditCardsIds != null ? Uow.CreditCards.GetByPredicate(t => creditCardsIds.Contains(t.Id)).ToList() : null;
    promotion.Branches = branchesIds != null ? Uow.Branches.GetByPredicate(t => branchesIds.Contains(t.Id)).ToList() : null;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Uow.Promotions.Update(promotion);
        Uow.Commit();
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

**In context**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>().
    HasMany(p => p.Promotions).
    WithMany(s => s.Branches).
    Map(
    m =>
    {
      m.MapLeftKey("BranchId");
      m.MapRightKey("PromotionId");
      m.ToTable("Branch_Promotion");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity<Promotion>().
    HasMany(tt => tt.CreditCards).
    WithMany(p => p.Promotions).
    Map(
    m =>
    {
     m.MapLeftKey("PromotionId");
     m.MapRightKey("CreditCardId");
     m.ToTable("Promotion_CreditCard");
    });
```

Am I suppose to call this?

```
promocion.CreditCards.Clear();
promocion.Branches.Clear();
```

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this solved it:

```
var promotion = Uow.Promotions.GetByPredicateIncluding(p => p.Id == promotionDto.Id, a => a.CreditCards, a => a.Branches).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

Which loads the entities related.

Seems they need to be loaded in order for Entity Framework to know if they are new or not.

If someone has a better explanation, please feel free to add any comment.

Best Regards. Guillermo.